# How do I update the color of the canvas.before class of a Kivy Label based on a function that returns True or False in Python?

Tags: python, android, canvas, kivy

How to dynamically modify a color of canvas. Before class of an label in kivy?

I have an function who if i press an button he will return True or False, if False: rounded rectangle color = red, if True: rounded rectangle color = green, basically is this, this is part of my code

### main.py

```
      # the "self" refer to "Screen" class in function
        # if True:
            if self.quests_list[start.questao-1]:
                with self.ids.revisao.canvas:
                    Color(0,1,0,1)
        # if False:
            else:
                with self.ids.revisao.canvas:
                    Color(1,0,0,1)
```

### app.kv

```
Label:
        id: revisao
        color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.41, "top":0.14}
        size_hint: 0.18, 0.05
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 0.28
            RoundedRectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                radius: [11]
```

nothing work, he don't return problems, but, just don't work